# Is it possible to change companion pet?

Tags: torchlight-2

As per [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/68525/27134), the only difference between companion pets is aesthetics and a special effect that occurs when you feed fish to your pet.

However, I'd still like to know is it possible to change companion pets once you have started a character, or does this involve starting a new character?

Comment: I found an fish which changes my pet into a mimic, which I think is really awesome :D

Comment: Why would I want to change Slinkyboots the ferret for something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you will have to start a new character.

A second option is too hope for a fishdrop that let's you change your pet permanently. Those do exist, but are very rare and hard to come by.

I personally found one that changes the pet permanently into a spider.

Answer (score 2):

The unofficial, fan-created editor called [Torchlight 2 Rapid Respec](http://clockworkcore.org/tl2rr.html) can change the pet type for your existing character.

Using this editor, you can change your pet type by using the [Aesthetics tab](http://clockworkcore.org/tl2rrhelp.html#changepettype).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the perma-morph fish effects for your pet are lost if you ever accidentally rclick another fish. The modding community of Torchlight II is currently building a lot of momentum, so keep an eye on the runic games modding forums ( http://forums.runicgames.com/viewforum.php?f=46 ) and hopefully some of the clever folk there will come up with a means to change the pet model for an existing character.